# React/Axios merge multiple array of objects based on key/value

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks

Grabbing data using Axios to build a Pokedex and based on different API calls, I would like to merge the data from the two, or three, calls into on. Making the calls, I currently have:

```
const [species, setSpecies] = useState([]);
const [types, setTypes] = useState([]);
const [sprites, setSprites] = useState([]);
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState();

axios.get('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species?limit=151')
  .then(res => {
    return axios.all(res.data.results.map(p => axios.get(p.url)));
  })
  .then(res => {
    setSpecies(res.map(p => p.data));
        
    return axios.all(res.map(s => axios.get(s.data.varieties[0].pokemon.url)));
  }).then(res => {
    setTypes(res.map(t => t.data.types));
    setSprites(res.map(s => s.data.sprites.front_default));
  });
```

I don't know if there's an easier/better way, but I would like the `setPokemon` to have the information from the species, types and sprites all merged by the id.

Thanks in advance for any help/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getPokemonData() {
  
  
  const pokemonData = await axios.get(
    "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species?limit=151"
  ); // 1
  let species = [];
  let types = [];
  let sprites = [];
  
  
  if (pokemonData) {
    const res2 = await axios.all(pokemonData.data.results.map((p) => axios.get(p.url)));
    
    if (res2) {
      species = res2.map((p) => p.data);
      const res3 = await axios.all(
        res2.map((s) => axios.get(s.data.varieties[0].pokemon.url))
      );
      
      if (res3) {
        let finalData = [...species];
        
        finalData = res3.map((elem, index) => {
          return {
            ...finalData[index],
            types: elem.data.types,
            sprites: elem.data.sprites.front_default,
          };
        });
        
        console.log(finalData);
        // now you should setState
        // setFinalData(finalData) 
      }
    }
  }
}


getPokemonData()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-VZ6m0F78+yo3sbu48gElK4irv2dzPoep8oo9LEjxviigcnnnNvnTOJRSrIhuFk68FMLOpiNz+T77nNY89rnWDg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Do you find it better? I am not sure but with this code, I am setting state only once, which will definitely be better. I am making use async await also for synchronous flow. But again usage of async await is up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply and the help. I got to thinking if just collecting all the data from both APIs and merging/joining the two would be better instead of taking snippets from one and adding it to the other. Would that go about the same as your suggestion? For example if I want all the data from `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species?limit=151` and all the data from `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151` and just mege data based on ID.

Comment: Any how you do it, the idea is to reduce the number of iterations through the array and also the set the state as minimum time as possible, so that the rerender doesnot happens unnecessarily.